# Array says null, even though indexes are being set

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get my script to put together a multi dimensional array. This normally should not be a problem, but for some reason everything is failing here and I have no idea why.

```
function getProducts(products){
    var allProducts = new Array();
    for(var p in products) if(products[p]){
        var groupName = products[p].otherGroupName;
        var code = (products[p].code.split("."))[0];
        if( !(products[p].commonName.length==0 && groupName=="") ){
            if(groupName=="") {
                groupName="Custom Admin Products";
            }
            if(!(groupName in allProducts)) {
                allProducts[groupName] = new Array();
            }
            var np = {};
            np.commonName = products[p].commonName;
            np.code = code;
            allProducts[groupName][np.code] = np;
        }
    }
    console.log(allProducts);
}
```

The argument of `products` is an object. You'll also see at the second to last line, I'm trying to log the array, and it should be filled but it shows `'[]'` in the log. If I log `allProducts[groupName][np.code]` it gives me a structure. So I'm completely lost.

Comment: Which is it? Are you getting `null` or a structure? Also, you're not really using arrays correctly. When you assign dynamic keys (`allProducts[groupName] = new Array()`, `allProducts[groupName][np.code] = np`) you're just using an array as an object.

Comment: Use object instead of array: `allProducts = {};`..... `allProducts[groupName] = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array object should have numeric indexes if you want an "associative array" like other dynamic languages like PHP you should use an Object. Instead declaring it as a `new Array()` or which is the same `a = []` try to use `a = {}`. That will allow you to use "named" indexes.

Also, using `.map()` seems to adjust to your necessity, which could improve the code legibility a little bit.

For more background here is the MDN doc of Array:

> Some people think that you shouldn't use an array as an associative array. In any case, you can use plain objects instead, although doing so comes with its own caveats.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description